# Render Images on local server with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**Firstly I will tell you about the project, you can skip this if you want...**

I am trying to make a software using flutter with which we can select an video or movie from the device and the server will serve it on the local network on the device's Ip address on the specified port. So I basically want to create an html page for that which will get served on local server when we will click button in flutter application. The idea is, we can select movies from our device and access them on the browser of our smart tv by putting the address of our server for example http://192.168.1.10:8080...

**Main question**

So after lot of research I found a way by which we start a server and render html in it. But I am unable to access and render files in the lib folder inside html..

**Here is the code of the function**

```
  startServer() async {
    var server = await HttpServer.bind(wifiIp, 8080);
    print("Server running on IP : " +
        server.address.toString() +
        " On Port : " +
        server.port.toString());
    await for (var request in server) {
      request.response
        ..headers.contentType =
            new ContentType("text", "html", charset: "utf-8")
        ..write('<h1>Hello World<h1><br><br> <img src="WW.png" alt="Cannot load file">')
        ..close();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: this is because your server did not handle `ww.png` file

Comment: Nowhere in your code you specify that you serve the lib directory files.
you need a static file server. or somehow serve files through a route, it may be done by reading the file in the flutter app and serving its bytes as a stream but i'm not sure if it could be done.

Comment: a hint: as a first line of the loop `await for (var request in server) {` add `print(request.uri`) and you will see what requests are sent to your server